# Multiple conditions (A and B) and not (C and D). How should the SQL query look like?

Tags: sql

Let's say we have a e-shop and all users' events in a single table.
The `events` table looks like this:

| id | user_id | type | time | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | visit_site | 2022-04-07 14:08 |  |
| 1 | 1 | add_item_to_cart | 2022-04-07 14:17 |  |
| 1 | 1 | add_item_to_cart | 2022-04-07 14:17 |  |
| 1 | 1 | checkout | 2022-04-07 14:22 |  |
| 1 | 1 | pay | 2022-04-07 14:25 |  |
| 1 | 2 | visit_site | 2022-04-07 14:30 |  |
| 1 | 2 | add_item_to_cart | 2022-04-07 14:40 |  |
| 1 | 2 | add_item_to_cart | 2022-04-07 14:44 |  |
| 1 | 2 | checkout | 2022-04-07 14:47 |  |
| 1 | 2 | pay | 2022-04-07 14:50 |  |

So there are multiple event types, they have timestamp (when it happened) and user that is the actor.

Let's say I want to find all users that did add items to cart and did buy on the next day.
I would assume the SQL query should be

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  user_id
FROM
  user_event
WHERE
  (type = 'add_item_to_cart' AND time BETWEEEN '2022-04-07 00:00' AND '2022-04-08 00:00') AND
  (type = 'buy' AND time BETWEEEN '2022-04-08 00:00' AND '2022-04-09 00:00')
```

Now, I understand that the above condition is basically equal to:

```
WHERE
  type = 'add_item_to_cart' AND time BETWEEEN '2022-04-07 00:00' AND '2022-04-08 00:00' AND
  type = 'buy' AND time BETWEEEN '2022-04-08 00:00' AND '2022-04-09 00:00'
```

which will return always empty results because we apply two conditions to column `time` with date ranges that don't intersect.

**So I have 3 questions**

1. How do I rewrite the query so that I get customers that added item to cart in 1 date range and bought in another date range ?
2. The above condition actually would match purchases made almost 2 days from adding to cart, i.e. '2022-04-07 00:01' - added to cart, '2022-04-08 23:58' - bought. How do I make a condition related to previous one, i.e. match buys strictly less than 1 day from last date of checkout (with matching user id) ?
3. Is there a way to force that events are related to the same user, so that query doesn't return user who bought item <1 day after someone else (with different `user_id`) added an item to cart ?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_, and a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM...`, to make code clearer - for everyone.

Comment: You would add a new filed (e.g. ref_order_id) in your event table which can group same events. Then you can get the desired result easily based on `pay` action.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `WHERE` statement within the same `SELECT`, you can try applying a `SELF JOIN` on the transactions made by the same users on a difference of one day:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.id,
    t1.user_id,
    t1.time AS time1,
    t1.type AS type1,
    t2.time AS time2,
    t2.type AS type2
FROM 
    user_event t1 
INNER JOIN 
    user_event t2
ON 
    t1.user_id = t2.user_id
AND 
    DATEDIFF(t2.time, t1.time) = 0
WHERE 
    t1.type = 'add_item_to_cart'
AND 
    t2.type = 'pay'
```

This solution answers to all your questions. You can find a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3066b711f72ce7444859be1a824d9eb3.
The input rows of this fiddle contain three kinds of users:

1. user who bought the same day,
2. user who bought the day after (targeted user),
3. user who bought two days after.

Comment: So, if I want to find users with 3 events, I need two joins ?

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov This solution is related to the three highly specific questions of your post, which involved the two events 'add_item_to_cart' and 'buy'. 

Do you need two joins for 3 events? Maybe or maybe not: it really depends on what you're looking for. What I can say for sure is that, if you want a "clean operation", you can't avoid at least one self join (more than one might be avoidable).

Can you provide a full generic example of what you need to do?

Comment: If you want to make it generic on events, you could also set the `WHERE` condition to be `t1.time <> t2.time`. Does it work for what you're looking for?

Comment: Let's say I want to get users who have:
1. Added an item to the cart (i.e. event type  "add_item_to_cart").
2. Went to checkout (event type "checkout").
3. Did *NOT* buy the items (event type "buy")
All 3 events in a period of time (1 day).

Comment: Gets slightly more complex than the solution published here. Refer to this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18fd875a8c9afdafca1ccea19b934649. Once you get the `events_inside_24h` table, you can play with conditions, regardless the complexity of your task.

Comment: Thank you a lot! That makes things much more clear )